# Дизайн приложения на андроид?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Делаю простой браузер в Android studio.
Как сделать полупрозрачный фон строки которая на картинке и чтобы открытые сайты начинались не от этого бара, а выше, под ним?

В styles.xml прописал `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>`

В color.xml `<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#28D3C1</color>`

Даже цвет не меняется на нужный, почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Цвет не меняется, потому что это работает только для API LEVEL > 19

Comment: эта строка по научному называется statusbar

Comment: Полупрозрачным его не сделать? Приложение под этот бар не поставить?

Comment: В statusbar'е обычно меняют цвет по градиенту ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библлиотеку [SystemBarTint](https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint), она по моему работает и на ниже версиях Lollypop.